# Integrate Bootstrap typeahead js with Bootstrap Datatable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I am using bootstrap data-tables [Datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) and bootstrap-taginput with [typehead.js](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead). I am new with bootstrap data-tables.

Here is the layout of my bootstrap data-tables [Example](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) and please consider Bootstrap tagging input box on top.

I want to search data-tables records with bootstrap tagging elements. but somehow i am unable to search with bootstrap tagging.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you start out with an empty array of the data you've got on your table you could do something clever by replacing the built in search box. In the example I'm linking to I don't care about one of the columns and the other columns need a little formatting:

```
var words = [];
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columns": [
        null, {
            "render": function(data, type, row) {
                ~words.indexOf(data) || words.push(data);
                return data;
            }
        }, {
            "render": function(data, type, row) {
                var d = data.replace(/\, /g, " ");
                ~words.indexOf(d) || words.push(d);
                return data.split(", ").join("<br/>");
            }
        }
    ],
    "initComplete": function() {
        var searchBox = $("#example_wrapper").find("input[type='search']");
        var searchBoxHolder = searchBox.parent();
        searchBox.empty().remove();
        searchBoxHolder.append($("<input/>", {
            "type": "text"
        }).typeahead({
            source: words,
            afterSelect: function(word) {
                table.search(word).draw();
            }
        }).on("keyup", function(x) {
            if (words.indexOf($(x.target).val()) === -1) {
                table.search($(x.target).val()).draw();
            }
        }));
    }
});
```

Basically what we're doing here is creating a blank array of search terms then iterating over each second and third cell and adding the term to the array if it doesn't exist. In the case of the third cell I need to clear some formatting (extra comma). Then we get the original search box and it's parent. Remove the original and append the new one to the parent. We then set it up as a `typeahead` with the list of search terms. We need to make sure it still acts like the original so we add the `keyup` function. I hope that makes sense.

Working example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/tjgh734e/), hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But i want built in search box and boostrap tagging  both with different text-boxes..  Thanks for above help it will give me help to moving forward.

Comment: How would you go on to populate this table with ajax and json?